# Firefox plugin for counting domain name hits

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is anyone aware of a Firefox plugin which counts the number of times that I visit each domain?

As an example, if I turn on FireBug and take my browser to the main Google homepage, I can see that the following sites are hit, and their frequencies:

- google.com x 5
- ssl.gstatic.com x 2

I would like a plugin that runs in the background, doesn't need switching on for specific pages, and just keeps a total of each site that I visit, against all tabs.

It's obviously technically possible because Firebug is almost doing that, it's just a bit of overkill and I'd need to activate it for every site I visit...

Answer (score 3):

I think it is build in by default in firefox. Right click on page and click "View Page Info" or click Tools -> Page Info. In last tab there is information how many times website was visited.

I don't know exactly how it is counted though.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I want the total during the whole browsing session (or even until I reset it), across all pages/tabs.